# Docusign email resource - Docusign tells us not to modify it

Tags: docusignapi

We have Docusign set up to use a customer's file number as the access key when they receive an envelope and they use their email/this key to do the signing.
We want to modify the Docusign email resource file to reword the footer info because the access code in the footer is not what the customer needs to enter for their signing ceremony and this is causing confusion. Docusign mentioned to us that if we modify this email resource file and later decide that are changes are no longer needed, that we can never go back to the standard email resource file. I can't understand why we can't go back to the standard file, it doesn't make sense. Has this happened to anyone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading a Branding Resource File only modifies parameters that are changed, so it's technically correct that you can "never go back" to the actual default by uploading additional resource files. You can upload a version of the default that has the impacted parameters slightly modified, and that will overwrite your more extreme changes.

The simplest way to reset a brand entirely is to delete the brand and recreate it. Alternatively, you can export the brand, modify the resulting file and upload it again.

Comment: Of course, you can have a copy of the original resource file saved away and upload that one to restore to the default settings if need be. I assume you can do something like that.

Comment: The original (or 'master') resource file is always available from the branding page. The issue is that if you upload the master resource file as-is, no changes are made. DocuSign only applies differences between the master and the file you upload.

Comment: So, for example, if I modify the resource file to modify the text in the footer and then upload it, Docusign will only take the difference between the 2 files and apply my mods, not completely replace the email resource file with the one I upload.

Comment: Is Docusign maintaining two different email resource files, the master and possibly a modified resource file that I modified?

Comment: That's correct. Your brand stores the modified resource file. If you were to take the original master file, edit a different parameter and upload it, your brand would then reflect your previously changed parameter as well as the new change.